# When to use -세요 and when -(으)ㅂ니다?

Tags: grammar, verb-endings, honorific, polite

This is one the questions [from the definition phase](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74083/korean-language/74164#74164) and I would like to get it discussed in the main site. (으)세요 and (으)ㅂ니다 are both honorific ending. When should we use one over the other?

Comment: Sorry; is the ㅂ there a typo?

Comment: no I don't think so

Comment: Huh. Does (스)ㅂ meant to create the sound 습? I've never seen it used that way before.

Comment: ah ok let me correct that

Comment: Usually in textbooks and classes things with different endings for consonants and vowels are shown with parenthesis. 


For example: ~(으)면, when the verb stem ends with a vowel (하다) dont add 으 (하면), otherwise (있다)  use  으 (있으면)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mixing two slightly different aspects of speech. One (합쇼체: ~습니다/ㅂ니다) is more of a level of formality due to setting and the other(시) is a level of respect towards the subject of your sentences.

~세요 is simply a combination of 해요체(어/아요) and the honorific marker (시). Honorifics are only used towards people of higher status (i.e. older people, individuals higher up in some hierarchy, etc..).

합쇼체, or deferential form, on the other hand denotes a degree of formality. Of course, you don't need to use honorifics in 합쇼체 unless the person you're speaking to requires so. However, you only use the form in situations like business environments, speeches, broadcasts, military settings, etc..